# Plot elliptic curve over real numbers

Tags: r, plot, elliptic-curve

How can I plot the elliptic curve

[image: formula]

over real numbers with R?

Comment: Something like `curve(x^3 - 3*x + 2, -10, 10)` maybe? Or `curve(x^3 - 3*x + 2, -2, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a feasible way by constructing the points manually.

```
df <- data.frame(x = -100:100, y = c(sqrt(x^3-3*x+ 2), -sqrt(x^3-3*x+ 2)))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to have problems as follows : Error in data.frame(x = -100:100, y = c(sqrt(x^3 - 3 * x + 2), -sqrt(x^3 -  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 201, 8

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(-300, 300, 0.1), y = c(sqrt(x^3 - 3*x + 2), -sqrt(x^3 - 3*x + 2)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will plot the elliptic curve your want

```
library(ggplot2)
# Define the elliptic curve equation
elliptic_curve <- function(x) {
  return (x^3 - 3*x + 2)
}

# Generate the x and y values for the plot
x_vals <- seq(-3, 3, by = 0.01)
y_vals <- sqrt(elliptic_curve(x_vals))

# Plot the points on the elliptic curve
ggplot(data.frame(x=x_vals, y=y_vals), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line()
```